# vue 3.3 generics and conditional properties

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I am exploring the generics feature on vue 3.3

and I have this idea of defining the type of an incoming prop based on the value of another prop value.

this is my actual component:

```
export interface OptionProps {
  id: string | number;
  name: string;
};
```

```
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T extends OptionProps">
import { computed } from "vue";
import {OptionProps} from './types.ts'

// define props by using generic
const props = defineProps<{
  options: T[];
  modelValue: T | T[];
  multiple: boolean;
}>();

// define emits
const emit = defineEmits<{
  "update:modelValue": [value: T|T[]];
}>();

// define proxyValue for modelValue to emit update:modelValue
const proxy = computed({
  get() {
    return props.modelValue;
  },
  set(value: T|T[]) {
    emit("update:modelValue", value);
  },
});
</script>
<template>
  <div>---- {{ options }} ----- {{ proxy }}</div>
</template>
```

what I want to do is to restrict the type of my modelValue based on the multiple value that means:

if multiple is true -> modelValue should be T[] but if it is false, modelValue should be T

so ideally I want the callers of my component to receive an error if they call it with an array modelValue and multiple false :

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Comp from './Comp.vue';
import { OptionProps } from './types.ts'


const result = ref<OptionProps[]>([{id: undefined, name: undefined}])

</script>

<template>
  <Comp 
  :model-value="result" 
  :options="[{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'}]"
   :multiple="false"
   />
</template>
```

I was exploring the idea of conditionals typing, but I don't have a clue about how to apply it in this case, is that even possible?

Comment: Prop validation is supposed to be generated from types, I'm quite sure you'll have to write it explicitly to be as advanced as this

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not the exact solution to your question but a workaround, afterall is the same desired output

You can edit your actual component to look something like this

```
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T extends OptionProps">
import { computed } from "vue";
import type { OptionProps } from "./types.ts";

// define props by using generic
const props = defineProps<{
  options: T[];
  singleModelValue?: T;
  multiModelValue?: T[];
}>();

// define emits
const emit = defineEmits<{
  "update:singleModelValue": [value: T | undefined];
  "update:multiModelValue": [value: T[] | undefined];
}>();

// define proxyValue for singleModelValue to emit update:modelValue
const singleProxy = computed({
  get() {
    return props?.singleModelValue || undefined;
  },
  set(value: T | undefined) {
    emit("update:singleModelValue", value);
  },
});

// define proxyValue for multiModelValue to emit update:multiModelValue
const multiProxy = computed({
  get() {
    return props?.multiModelValue || [];
  },
  set(value: T[] | undefined) {
    emit("update:multiModelValue", value);
  },
});
</script>
<template>
  <div>---- {{ options }} ----- {{ singleProxy ?? multiProxy }}</div>
</template>
```

and use it like this

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import Comp from "./components/Comp.vue";
import type { OptionProps } from "./components/types.ts";

const single_result = ref<OptionProps>({ id: 1, name: "hello" });
const multi_result = ref<OptionProps[]>([{ id: 1, name: "hello" }]);
</script>

<template>
  <Comp
    :single-model-value="single_result"
    :options="[
      { id: 1, name: 'one' },
      { id: 2, name: 'two' },
    ]"
  />
  <br />
  <Comp
    :multi-model-value="multi_result"
    :options="[
      { id: 1, name: 'one' },
      { id: 2, name: 'two' },
    ]"
  />
</template>
```

so instead of using the multiple, you can create two props, one to handle array and the other which will handle the one one that is not an array.
Hope you find this helpful.